# Django Test Client client.post() sends GET request?

Tags: django, http

I am new to Python and Django. I did a experiment on enforcing request method (e.g. for certain url you can only use GET). Here is my code.

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
client = Client()

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_request_method:
        """ Sending wrong request methods should result in 405 error """
        self.assertEqual(client.post('/mytest', follow = True).status_code, 405)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^mytest/', views.mytest, name = 'mytest'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def mytest(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse("Not implemented", status = 500)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Only GET method allowed", status = 405)
```

But the test always returns status 500.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309178/django-test-client-doesnt-call-post-but-get) that this may be related to using `follow=True` in the `client.post()` call. However if I use `follow=False` I will get status 301 instead.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen you are absolutely right! After removing the tailing slash i got correct status code. Thank you! (As noted I am new to this stuff...) Please post your reply as an answer.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you should prefer `reverse('mytest')` over hardcoding the url. It will always return the canonical url, so you won't encounter any redirects.

Comment: @knbk Can you please give me a short example? I don't understand what you mean by saying "reverse(my test)"

Comment: Just do `from django.urls import reverse`, then instead of `'/mytest'`, you use the result of `reverse('mytest')`. `mytest` is the name you gave your url. You can read more in [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does it perhaps redirect `/mytest` to `/mytest/`? [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash) suggests that by default, a trailing slash is added by doing a redirect if no URL pattern matches without the slash, and to quote:

> Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.

A request caused by commonly used redirect status codes is always a GET request. You could either make the request to `/mytest/` or remove the trailing slash from your URL pattern.